# debug_backtrace() from registered shutdown function in PHP

Tags: php, stack-trace, shutdown-hook, debug-backtrace

While tinkering for an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7241541/how-to-check-if-exit-is-clean-in-a-shutdown-function-in-php), I found that `debug_backtrace()` doesn't trace beyond the function registered to `register_shutdown_function()`, when called from within it.

This was mentioned in [this comment](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php#95256) for [`register_shutdown_function()`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php) in the PHP docs, stating:

> You may get the idea to call debug_backtrace or debug_print_backtrace from inside a shutdown function, to trace where a fatal error occurred. Unfortunately, these functions will not work inside a shutdown function.

Explained with a bit more detail, comments on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216963/fastest-way-to-determine-where-php-script-exits/216979#216979) state:

> Doesn't work. The shutdown function occurs after the stack has unwinded. There is no stack information to dump.

Is there any way to circumvent this, forcing PHP to hold the stack trace until the process has terminated altogether, or should we accept it as a given due to PHP internals?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is there any way to circumvent this, forcing PHP to hold the stack trace

That's rather meaningless, when the registered function is invoked, all your defined functions have returned or been cleared down from the stack.

If you need to know where your code exited, then you need to instrument your code.

Comment: Thanks @symcbean - Given all other functions in a given execution have returned, and we've bubbled back up to global scope, of course; however, the part where incomplete function calls are being cleared from the stack (*given `exit` is called at some arbitrary depth of nested calls*) is what I find unfortunate, and not meaningless. I never use `exit` for execution control, favoring exceptions to handle my error logic; this was more of an academic inquiry, rather than real-world. Still though, it makes sense in my mind that the stack should be preserved until the process is killed completely.

Comment: Than what would happen when your registered shutdown function returned?

Comment: Touche, sir; I just thought PHP would (*should*) keep the stack at script termination, check for handlers, execute handlers, wash-rinse-repeat until the queue is empty, and **then** end execution.

Comment: You can use [error_get_last](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-get-last.php) to find where the error was raised, but it won't give you the stack.

Answer (score 19):

This is a **very expensive** solution. I never used [`register_tick_function()`](http://php.net/manual/function.register-tick-function.php) or [`tick`](http://php.net/manual/control-structures.declare.php) and I'm not sure if it works as expected.

```
declare(ticks=1);

function tick_handler() {
    global $backtrace;
    $backtrace = debug_backtrace();
}
register_tick_function('tick_handler');



function shutdown() {
    global $backtrace;
    // do check if $backtrace contains a fatal error...
    var_dump($backtrace);
}
register_shutdown_function('shutdown');
```

Comment: Thanks @powtac - Great solution, however it didn't work. I certainly see where you were going with that. I fooled with it a bit, but with no success yet.

Comment: thats clever for sure. i didnt know about tick function

Comment: Was searching for same and found this - https://gist.github.com/rmbl/5780995. Didn't try though. Note `declare(ticks=1);` at the end

Comment: You need the `declare(ticks=1)` statement on every file of your project for this to work

Answer (score 7):

In [XDebug](http://xdebug.org/) extension, there is a [`xdebug_get_function_stack()`](http://xdebug.org/docs/stack_trace#xdebug_get_function_stack) function.

This one works similar to PHP's internal `debug_backtrace()`, but keeps the trace even in shutdown handler.

You won't get the exact exit point though, only the last executed function before the shutdown occured (triggered by `die()`/`exit()` call or error).

This is of course suitable only for development environment.

Comment: quirk:  doesn't work for uncaught exceptions... unless a default exception handler has been set with [set_exception_handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php)

Comment: quirk #2:  `xdebug_get_function_stack()` begins with shutdown-function if there was a parse error

Answer (score 5):

From my experience, the shutdown function starts with a clean stack, and it has no access to the "original" stack (as it no longer exists at that point).

Unfortunately, there is no way to save that original stack.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your registered shutdown function you can get backtrace by [error_get_last](http://www.php.net/error_get_last) function. Works for me in PHP7.

Comment: This only gets the file and line where the error occurred - not the full backtrace.