# Is there a way to know the exit status code from within a shutdown function?

Tags: php

Is there a way to know the value passed to `exit()` from within a shutdown function?

For example:

```
<?php

function handleShutdown(){
    // Is there a way to know the value passed to exit() at this point?

    someCleanup();
}

register_shutdown_function('handleShutdown');

if(somethingWentWrong()){
    exit(3);
}

exit(0);
```

This is in the context of a complex set of legacy scripts running in CLI mode. I am looking for a solution to instrument their exit status within php that does not involve modifying all the points where the scripts invoke `exit()` (so, not using a global variable, `define` or forking the whole script).

There is this other [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7241541/how-to-check-if-exit-is-clean-in-a-shutdown-function-in-php) asking to know whether the exit was is "clean", but it does not address the exit code at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [install uopz](https://www.php.net/manual/en/uopz.installation.php), which will give you [uopz_get_exit_status()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uopz-get-exit-status.php).

Then use it in your `handleShutdown` function:

```php
$exitCode = uopz_get_exit_status();
```

Comment: The existence of `uopz_get_exit_status()` seems to prove that there is no native way. Unfortunately, I cannot easily install uopz at the moment, but this seems to be a good plan B.